# How to determine two unknown variables from experiment?

Tags: python, math, bluetooth-lowenergy, linear-regression

I am currently working on a Bluetooth Low Energy distance calculation project. During my research, I've encountered the [Log distance path loss model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-distance_path_loss_model) formula and I want to determine coefficients based on experiment.

The general formula I have is :

```
Pd = P0 - 10 * n * log(d)
```

I want to determine through experiment the best values that can be given to `n` and `P0` in order to get the closest results from the reality. So let's say I can get a lot of measures of `d` and `Pd` like :

```
| d (meters) | 2  | 3   | etc
| Pd(dBm)    |-58 | -60 | etc
```

As said in [this article](http://tam.unige.ch/assets/documents/publications/SENSORCOMM2014_Ionescu.pdf) (just for reference, no need to read it) they used linear regression to get the best values of those coefficients, but I'm really lost. If you have any hint preferably in Python, you're welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have a great answer for you, but if you haven't looked, I would strongly suggest looking at **scipy**.  I believe this is right up that alley

Comment: This doesn't really look like a programming question. Do you know how to apply linear regression to your problem?

Comment: Well I'm looking for some code here because I'm really lost

Comment: What constitutes the best values of `n` and `P0`? There are an infinite number of value combinations that will work for a given `d` and `Pd`.